# random.choice always same

Tags: python

I have a quick question. I'm currently using random.choice() to pick from a list and was wondering why it always calls the same item. It changes once I stop the program and restart it. Could anyone explain to me how the random class works and makes it so it does this?

Thanks

Comment: `select()` isn't broken.  The error is somewhere in your code, so please show your code.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: Are you using `random.Random(some_value)` with the same value every time you use it for the length of the program?

Comment: @agf: My guess is this is either a default argument or something like `a = [[0]] * 10; for x in a: x[0] = random.choice(...)`.

Comment: Do you seed the random generator in any way (maybe before every choice)?

Comment: I think OP runs this: `b = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5])`, and then prints `b` in the terminal, and gets the same number every time.

Comment: We do need to see the code. If you're seeding the random generator, that could be the problem. Alternatively, are you sure your list has more than 1 unique entry? When I run the code that @Akavall lists above, it gives different results and works as expected.

Comment: @EMS, What I mean is run `b = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5])`, then type `b` in the terminal, then type in the terminal again (without rerunning `b = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5])`), every `b` should be the same.

Comment: I see. You conjecture the OP was issuing: `b = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5]); print b; print b; print b; ...` or something like that.

Comment: Another reason could be doing `random.seed(1); random.choice(b)` repeatedly

Answer (score 11):

This is my guess as to what you are most likely doing:

```
import random

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
random.Random(500).choice(l)
# 4
random.Random(500).choice(l)
# 4
random.Random(500).choice(l)
# 4
```

If you are using the actual Random class with the same seed, and making a new instance each time, then you are performing the same pseudo random operation. This is actually a feature (seeding) to let you have a reproducible randomization in future runs of your routine.

Either do this with a seed:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
r = random.Random(500) # seed number is arbitrary 
r.choice(l)
r.choice(l)
```

Or use the convenience method:  `random.choice(l)`

Comment: I would say this is unlikely: "It changes once I stop the program and restart it."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its 11 years late

Incase anyone is having the same issue I had the "random.choice" command outside a while loop

Put it inside the while loop it works now