# always got the same output with random.choice in a function

Tags: python-3.x

I tried using for-loop to exec my function but its always the same result.

```
import random

def main(arr):
  result = random.choice(arr)
  ...some code...

  return len(result)

for i in range(100):
  main(arr)
```

I could only get diff result from stop/run the terminal. Anyone know why?

my question is the same as this one. [random.choice always same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181932/random-choice-always-same)

```
import random

results = []
with open('kargerMinCut.txt') as inputfile:
for line in inputfile:
    results.append(line.strip().split('\t'))


def contract(arr):

  while len(arr) > 2:

    # Generate random number in list of lists
    # ranList = random.choice(arr)
    ranList = arr[np.random.choice(len(arr))]
    ranNum = random.choice(ranList[1:])

    # retrieve the index of the random number
    listIndex = arr.index(ranList)

    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if arr[i][0] == ranNum:
            targetList = i
            break
    target = ranList[0]
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if i == listIndex:
            arr[i].pop(0)
            arr[i] = [x for x in arr[i] if x != ranNum]
        elif i == targetList:
            arr[i] = [x for x in arr[i] if x != target]
        else:
            for index, item in enumerate(arr[i]):
                if item == target:
                    arr[i][index] = ranNum
    arr[targetList] += arr[listIndex]
    del arr[listIndex]

return len(arr[0])-1
```

the arr would be like this

```
array = [[1,2,3,4],[2,1,3,4],[3,1,2,4],[4,1,2,3]]
```

Comment: what is the `arr` argument that you pass into `main` in your `for-loop`?

Comment: its a 2d array. im posting my code above.
since i want to test the function output and get the lowest one, but I cant test it using a for loop. It will give me the same result within the for-loop. I guess it just copy the function output for N times, instead of running the function N times?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you do inside your function but I've got the normal result. And in the question what you linked to the person just used **seed**. This is kinda pseudorandom that gives you all the time the same random output. Here is the  [link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) to deep your knowledge about pseudorandom

```
import random

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

def main(arr):
    result = random.choice(arr)
    print(result)

for i in range(100):
    main(arr)
```

The result is as it has to be:

```
1
3
5
3
4
3
1
4
4
3
2
```