# Reset random call

Tags: python, random, blackjack

I am making a blackjack game for class, my code works and there are no errors persay, but every time I call the play function it doesn't reset the cards you are dealt. It works if you stop and run the program again but when you say yes to try again it gives you and the dealer the same cards everytime. It isn't the same as that other question do doen't suggest it, this a different situation with a specific fix.

Here is the code:

```
import random

playerIn = True
dealerIn = True

    

deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
       'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
Typecard = ['Of Hearts', 'Of Spades', 'Of Clubs', 'Of Diamonds']
playerHand = []
dealerHand = []

def dealCard(turn):
    card = random.choice(deck)
    turn.append(card)
    deck.remove(card)

def total(turn):
     total = 0
     face = ['J', 'K', 'Q' ]
     for card in turn:
         if card in range(1, 11):
             total += card
         elif card in face:
             total += 10
         else:
             if total > 11:
                 total += 1
             else:
                total += 11
     return total

def tryAgain():
    again = input("Would you like to play again, type yes or no: ").lower()

    if again == "yes":
        print("Ok")
        play()

    elif again == "no":
        print(f"Bye {name}")

def revealDealerHand():
     if len (dealerHand) == 2:
         return dealerHand[0]
     elif len (dealerHand) > 2:
         return dealerHand[0], dealerHand[1]

for _ in range(2):
    dealCard(dealerHand)
    dealCard(playerHand)

def play():
    while playerIn or dealerIn:
        print(f"\nDealer has {revealDealerHand()} and X")
        print(f"\nYou have {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)}")
        if playerIn:
            stayOrHit = input("\nWould you like to stay or hit (type 1 for stay and 2 for hit): ").lower()
        if total(dealerHand) > 16:
            dealerIn = False

        else:
            dealCard(dealerHand)
        
        if stayOrHit == "1":
            break

        else:
            dealCard(playerHand)
        if total(playerHand) >= 21:
            break
        elif total(dealerHand) >= 21:
            break


    if total(playerHand) == 21:
        print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
        print(f"BLACKJAAACK! Nice one {name}")
        tryAgain()

    elif total(dealerHand) == 21:
        print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
        print("BLACKJACK, Dealer wins you lose, HA!")
        tryAgain()

    elif total(playerHand) > 21:
        print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
        print("You bust loser, Dealer wins.")
        tryAgain()

    elif total(dealerHand) > 21:
        print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
        print(f"The dealer busts, You win {name}!")
        tryAgain()

    elif 21 - total(dealerHand) < 21 - total(playerHand):
        print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
        print("Dealer Wins, loser.")
        tryAgain()

    elif 21 - total(playerHand) < 21 - total(dealerHand):
        print(f"\nYou have a hand of {playerHand} for a total of {total(playerHand)} and the dealer has {dealerHand} for a total of {total(dealerHand)}")
        print(f"You Win {name}!")
        tryAgain()



name = input("Please type you name: ")
play()
```

I hvaen't found anything on this problem so nothing really.

Comment: Find the place in the code where you first create the hand. Then try to think - will this code be run ever again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random.choice always same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181932/random-choice-always-same)

Comment: This should do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181932/random-choice-always-same

Comment: Thanks matszwejeca, that helped, that lick everyone sends doesn't really work

Comment: nope that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when a second game starts there is no code that changes the hands of both players. They still have the cards of the previous game.

The quick fix is to add the following code at the top of the `play` function:

```
def play():
    # Return all cards to the deck
    deck.extend(playerHand)
    deck.extend(dealerHand)
    # ...they should no longer be in any hands
    playerHand.clear()  
    dealerHand.clear()
    # Deal new cards from the full deck
    for _ in range(2):
        dealCard(dealerHand)
        dealCard(playerHand)
```

And this `for` loop can be removed from the top-level code (just above `def play`).

Not your question, but there is much to be improved in your code:

- Minimise the use of global names
- Give functions parameters where appropriate
- Use classes to combine data with the functions on that data
- Instead of `random.choice`, use `random.shuffle` to shuffle the deck and then you can just pop the cards from the deck.
- Don't call `play()` recursively: this consumes the call stack. Instead have a main loop that continues to iterate and call `play` for as long as the user wants to.